# Is this a correct understanding of how Scala provides multiple inheritance without causing the Diamond issue

Tags: scala, inheritance, mixins

Below code:

```
trait t1 {
    def printt1 = println("In t1")
}

trait t2 {
    def printt1 = println("In t2")
}

class cclass extends t1 with t2
```

Cause this compile-time error:

```
class cclass inherits conflicting members: method printt1 in trait t1 of type => Unit and method printt1 in trait t2 
 of type => Unit (Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in class cclass.)
```

So this is providing compile time checking which does not allow multiple inheritance but does allow mixins while also preventing the Diamond problem : "multiple inheritance has been a touchy issue for many years[citation needed], with opponents pointing to its increased complexity and ambiguity in situations such as the "diamond problem", where it may be ambiguous as to which parent class a particular feature is inherited from if more than one parent class implements said feature." source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

In order to fix compile time error above I just override t1 :

```
class cclass extends t1 with t2 {

    override def printt1 = println("In cclass")

}
```

Is this the primary shortcoming (Diamond problem) Scala is overcoming with respect to Java and multiple inheritance ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no diamond problem in your code. To quote Wikipedia:

> The "diamond problem" ...  is an ambiguity that arises when two
>   classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and
>   C.

Here is an example that demonstrates Scala's handling of the diamond problem:

```
trait A {
  def x = 1
}

trait B extends A {
  override def x = 2
}

trait C extends A
class D extends B with C

(new D).x // == 2
```

Scala "linearizes" the lookup of methods from traits. For `D`, it starts with `D` itself, and then looks at every class or trait it inherits from, starting from the right. This is a depth-first search, so the order is `D -> C -> A -> B -> A`, however duplicates (which indicate a diamond problem) are eliminated leaving the last in the list, so it becomes `D -> C -> B -> A`.

However, this code:

```
trait A[A] {
  val x: A
}

trait B extends A[Int]
trait C extends A[String]
trait D extends B with C
```

produces this error:

```
trait D inherits different type instances of trait A:
  A[String] and A[Int]
```

Showing that Scala still has a diamond problem in certain circumstances.

Comment: "D -> C -> B -> A" Well, it ends with A, why it prints value from B then?

Comment: And what are the rules of transformation "D -> C -> A -> B -> A" into "D -> C -> B -> A"? Remove duplicates going from right to left?

Comment: @MaxNevermind Both of your questions are answered in the answer body

Comment: Thank you so much for the nice and clean example! It's really helped!