# Concept of Linearization in Scala and behaviour of super

Tags: scala, traits, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following example of traits:

```java
trait TextileEngineer extends Engineer {
  override def nameIt = {println("TextileEngineer"); super.nameIt;}
}
trait FabricEngineer extends Engineer {
  override def nameIt = {println("FabricEngineer"); super.nameIt;}
}

trait Engineer extends Person {
  override def nameIt = {println("Engineer"); super.nameIt;}
}
trait ClothMaker extends Trader {
  override def nameIt = {println("ClothMaker"); super.nameIt;}
}
trait Trader {
  def nameIt = println("Trader");
}

trait Parent extends Person with Human {
  override def nameIt = {println("Parent"); super.nameIt;}
}
trait Person extends Human {
  override def nameIt = {println("Person"); super.nameIt;}
}
trait Human {
  def nameIt = {println("Human");}
}

object Linear extends App {
  val data = new TheSmiths {}
  data.nameIt
}

trait TheSmiths extends FabricEngineer with TextileEngineer with ClothMaker with Parent {
  override def nameIt: Unit = super[TextileEngineer].nameIt //-----------override:1
  override def nameIt: Unit = super[FabricEngineer].nameIt //------------override:2
  override def nameIt: Unit = super.nameIt //------------override:3
}
```

- when in the final trait - the **override:1** is used - the output is -

```
TextileEngineer
FabricEngineer
Engineer
Person
Human
```

- but when **override:2** is used - the answer is -

```
FabricEngineer
Engineer
Person
Human
```

- But when the **override:3** is used - the answer is - **Why is the hierarchy not followed upto the `Human` when the trait `Parent` is the part of other hierarchy?**

```
Parent
ClothMaker
Trader
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is because `Trader` does not call `super` inside `nameIt`:

```
trait Trader {
  def nameIt = println("Trader");
}
```

The long answer is because linearization begins with `TheSmiths` itself, then checks every class or trait it inherits from, starting from the rightmost extended trait to the leftmost extended trait (or class if you extend one), but in a depth-first search manner.

So for example, your linearization of `TheSmiths` is:

```
TheSmiths -> Parent -> Human -> Person -> Human -> ClothMaker -> Trader -> TextileEngineer -> 
Engineer -> Person -> Human -> FabricEngineer -> Engineer -> Person -> Human
```

Now duplicates (which indicate a [diamond problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152579/2205089)) are eliminated leaving the last occurrence of every type in the list.

Let's understand this first through a simpler example. `Parent` also has a diamond problem: it inherits `Human` once directly through mixing, and another one through extending `Person` which also mixes in `Human`. So the initial linearization should be:

```
Parent -> Human -> Person -> Human
```

Now we have to remove duplicates and keep the last occurrence of every type. So the linearization of `Parent` becomes:

```
Parent -> Person -> Human
```

As we can see, in this case - writing `with Human` - had no effect in the definition of `Parent`.

Coming back, using the same pattern, the actual linearization of `TheSmiths` becomes:

```
TheSmiths -> Parent -> ClothMaker -> Trader -> TextileEngineer -> FabricEngineer -> 
Engineer -> Person -> Human
```

This is the linearization that occurs when you instantiate `TheSmiths` using `new`.

> Then, whenever you call `super` inside one of those classes, the
> invoked method is the next one up the chain. If all of the methods but
> the last one call super, the net result is *stackable behavior*.
> ([Programming in Scala](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_4ed))

Linearization also serves as a way of verifying the output of the 2 other examples you gave.